# How to set default values for query params based on dynamic segment?

Tags: ember.js

I am creating universal grid for some entities. For that I added this in routes:

```
this.route('record', { path: '/record' },function() {
   this.route('index', {path: '/:entity'});
   this.route('view', {path: '/:entity/:record_id'});
});
```

and created new "index" route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  entity: '',

  queryParams: {
    sort: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    var entity = transition.params[this.get('routeName')].entity;

    this.set('entity', entity);
  },

  model: function(params) {
    delete params.entity;

    return this.store.findQuery(this.get('entity'), params);
  },
}
```

my controller

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['sort'],

  sort: ''
}
```

how can I set default value for the "sort" based on dynamic segment?
For example in my settings I store sort values for all entites:

```
'settings.user.sort': 'email ASC',
'settings.company.sort': 'name ASC',
```

I tried to define "sort" as computed property, but its "get" method is called in time when I can't get a value of dynamic segment from currentHadlerInfo or from route.

Also defining of the property "sort" as computed property has strange effect, for example, when I define it as

```
sort: 'email ASC'
```

in my template it is displayed via {{sort}} as expected (email ASC).
but when I return a value from computed property, I see empty value in my template and this affects on a work of components (I can't get current sorted column)

What can I do?..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough implementation of setting the sort properties based on dynamic segment values. The code will look like

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#link-to 'sort' model.settings.user.sort}}Sort{{/link-to}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sort">
  <ul>
  {{#each arrangedContent as |item|}}
    <li>{{item.val}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

var settings = Em.Object.create({
  settings: {
    user: {
      sort: 'val ASC'
    }
  }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('sort', {path: '/:sortParams'});
});

App.SortRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  params: null, 

  model: function(params) {
    this.set('params', params);
    return [{val:1}, {val:5}, {val:0}];
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);

    var props = this.get('params').sortParams.split(' ');
    var property = [props[0]];
    var order = props[1] === 'ASC'? true : false;

    controller.set('sortProperties', property);
    controller.set('sortAscending', order);
  }
});
```

[**The working demo can be found here.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sosali/1/edit?html,js,output).

As you can see I access the params object in the `model` hook and store it on the route. In the `setupController` hook I access the params and set the required values on the controller.